# How do I unlock other archers?

Tags: towerfall-ascension

In Towerfall you only start out with four archers but I know that there are others. How do I unlock these other characters?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I unlocked the cyan archer by completing quest mode on normal including the unlockabale level "the sunken city" after you fight "The king's court." after that you have to fight and beat the cyan archer to unlock it.

I unlocked the white archer by playing versus on the moonstone map. One of the maps has an archer trapped in a gem, shoot it to unlock that archer.

I unlocked the purple archer by playing versus on twilight spire. This event is triggered when doing a match with Last of the Order vs. Turncloak Soldier, and opens a portal in the level through which monsters spawn (as in quest mode). This event is only triggered sometimes, and will only unlock the purple archer if you kill all the enemies.

I unlocked the yellow archer after finding 7 hidden "yellow triangles" hidden throughout the training missions. Here are the locations of three of them (Spellforge 2 has an explodable block that holds a statue of the Yellow Archer and a symbol representing areas that hold triangles, i.e, moon for Moonstone, crossed arrows for Sacred Ground, sadly these only tell area, not specific number trial). Here they are in order:

- One is in Sacred Ground 2. You have to light the unlit brazier with a fire arrow.
- One is in Twilight Spire 2. You have to step in the top-left corner to reveal it.
- One is behind the bottom left wall in Backfire 3.
- One is behind the upper left wall in Thornwood 3
- One is under the blue block in Kings Court 1 (must be reached before becoming solid,  shoot an arrow into it to make it wait for you).
- One is in Sunken City 3, near the bottom-most area and to the right.
- One is in Moonstone 3, you have to blow up the glass to the left of where you start with a bomb arrow, then it is in that area.

Comment: More information would help - Which quest did you complete? How many levels do you have unlocked? Which archer did you unlock?

Comment: Sorry, I wrote this in haste.

Comment: Thanks for updating it. Your answer now is rather descriptive.

Answer (score 8):

-Yellow Triangle Guide-

After much frustration & searching, I've found all seven yellow triangles. Listed below are their locations, as well as how to unlock the yellow archer.

1. Sacred Ground II - There is an unlit torch at the top left of the screen. Standing to the left of the lit torch beside it, fire an arrow through the flame to light the unlit torch; the chest will appear with your triangle.
2. Twilight Spire II - There is an alcove directly about your spawn point. Using jump then dodge in mid air, climb to the alcove. Upon arrival, the chest will appear.
3. Backfire III - On the bottom left wall, there is a false wall. Standing in the very bottom left corner, while holding left, jump. You should grab on to a ledge; pull yourself up in the room, & chest is waiting.
4. Thornwood III - At the top left, where the dummy is, is a false wall. Drop through the floor to the top while hugging the wall. Walk through the dummy into the false wall, wrapping around to the right side of the screen. Keep walking through the left wall of the second room to find another room, with your chest waiting.
5. King's Court I - There are three red blocks and one outline of a block in the middle-right area. Quickly run in to the outline, dashing at the last second to make it in. You will fall through the floor, with the chest waiting to the left.
6. Sunken City III -  On the very bottom, across from the bottom dummy, is a little one-block tall ledge. Get on the ledge, then walk to the right through the wall. Inside the room is your chest.
7. Moonstone III - This is a tough one. The crystal walls in the middle are breakable, but only if a bomb arrow hits a the bottom inside the crystal. Your target is the crystal on the right. With careful timing, using the bomb arrows, shoot the ledge it is resting against. With a little luck, the crystal wall will explode, allowing you to climb over the crystal on the left. Once inside the room, above the dummy on the left is a false ceiling. Jump then dodge your way inside, to claim your final triangle.

To put those hard earned triangles to good use, go to Tower Forge II. In the middle area, beneath the floating piece, are two little rocks. Using the Super bomb arrows, shoot the ground, then quickly get out of the blast zone. After they're destroyed, drop down to find the yellow archer, frozen. Stand around for a little bit for him to break free. Return to the map, with an animation showing your new character!

I hope this helps those of you looking for the Yellow Archer!

Comment: Great answer! I didn't find the Moonstone III to be that difficult to blow-up the crystal on the right. Shooting the ceiling in diagonal (TOP-LEFT) once is enough to take care of it with the bomb-arrow.

Answer (score 0):

easiest way to unlock all, just open the `tf_saveData` file with notepad, go to the bottom, you will see unlocks, just change every false into true, and voila, all unlocked.
I lost my saved chars and stats, just had to do this to open them up again

Answer (score -5):

I unlocked the purple archer by playing Last man standing and got the purple archer.

Comment: You should only post an answer if you can actually provide a complete answer or at least one you think is complete. Bits of information are better suited as comments, which you will be able to post once you have enough reputation.