# How to unlock secret stage Sacred Ground 2 in TowerFall Ascension?

Tags: towerfall-ascension

Currently I am trying to unlock the yellow archer and am trying to collect all 7 yellow triangles.

However, many of the locations are "Sacred Ground 2" or "Towerfall 2".
When I go to my stage selection, I dont have either of those, and the wave 2 for each looks nothing like the pictures of Sacred Ground 2, or any of the other stages that supposedly have the yellow triangles.

How do I find these stages?

Comment: See [this answer](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/159687/56730) for the list of stages and a text description (give it a shot first). You'll also need to unlock stages you don't have. See [here](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/159860/56730) for that list

Comment: I have all the stages listed there with the exception of gauntlet and gauntlet 2. I dont see anything on how to find any of the level 2 or level 3 stages. Ive played a bunch of the in hardcore, only to find its the same stage, just harder

Comment: Are you in the Trials mode? There's a separate mode where these triangles are found.

Comment: I was not, that explains why I didnt even see the option for it. Ive now found the missions, thank you

Comment: @BenCraig If you were able to solve your issue, please add your solution as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the triangles are not in the main stage selection.

Instead, they are in the 'Trials' section of the game, and are then easily obtained.